# Why can’t I use $F=ma$ to calculate the orbital path of a planet?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, orbital-motion

Why doesn’t gravitational acceleration over time predict the planet's distance from the Sun? Gravity is toward one point and over time you should be able to predict the distance.

If the planet is stationary, relative to the Sun, we would be able to predict the distance at any instant in time later.

If the orbit is elliptical, then the planet could have a radial velocity toward or opposite the Sun. Using the gravitational acceleration formula $u/r^2$ we should still be able to predict distance at a short or long duration in time later but this doesn't work. Why?

Comment: It *does* work, but you must treat displacements, velocities and accelerations as vectors and be prepared to use calculus methods.

Comment: @Nectac Perhaps you can edit your answer to explain *why* you think using $F=ma$ doesn't work for orbits ?

Comment: Feynman shows how to do it in the beginning of the first volume of his lectures.  Without using integrals, just by applying Newton's law of motion step by step.

Answer (score 8):

> Why doesn’t gravitational acceleration over time predict the planet's distance from the sun? Gravity is toward one point and over time you should be able to predict the distance.

Yep! You are right! In Newtonian mechanics as long as you know the force $\mathbf F$, the initial position $\mathbf x(0)$, and the initial velocity $\mathbf v(0)=\dot{\mathbf x}(0)$ then using Newton's second law you can set up a differential equation $\ddot{\mathbf x}=\mathbf F/m$ and determine the trajectory $\mathbf x(t)$. This works fine for any force, including Newtonian gravity.

So contrary to the rest of the question, this can be done. Of course Newtonian mechanics and Newtonian gravity themselves are not sufficient to explain certain physical phenomena, but I don't think that is what you are getting at here. It should also be noted that not all systems involving Newtonian gravity and Newtonian mechanics have nice solutions you can write out; sometimes you will need to resort to numerical methods to solve the differential equation(s).

Comment: It seems the OP is more confused about *how* to actually compute such a trajectory for an orbit...?

Comment: @DaddyKropotkin It looks like the OP thinks it is not possible. My answer addresses this concern by saying it is possible. If you want to post an answer for your interpretation you should :)

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the trajectory of a planet by brute force, using only algebra, from Newton's equation for the force of gravity. You have to start with initial conditions for position and velocity. And you have to choose how small your time intervals will be. The smaller the intervals are the more accurate the calculated trajectory will be. [Richard Feynman does this in lecture 9 of his Lectures on Physics](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_09.html).

You calculate the force and acceleration at the first position. Then you calculate the next position based on that and the initial velocity. Repeat this process at each point. At each point you update the position, velocity and acceleration.

> "So, as we said, we began this chapter not knowing how to calculate even the motion of a mass on a spring. Now, armed with the tremendous power of Newton’s laws, we can not only calculate such simple motions but also, given only a machine to handle the arithmetic, even the tremendously complex motions of the planets, to as high a degree of precision as we wish!"

Answer (score 0):

It works, it's just complicated.

> If the planet is stationary, relative to the Sun, we would be able to predict the distance at any instant in time later.

But the planet isn't stationary relative to the Sun. If it were stationary it would be a free-falling object and you can calculate its acceleration using standard kinematic equations, but the fact that it is moving throws a wrench into this.

> If the orbit is elliptical, then the planet could have a radial velocity toward or opposite the Sun. Using the gravitational acceleration formula $u/r^2$ we should still be able to predict distance at a short or long duration in time later but this doesn't work. Why?

We see a similar problem here. The gravitational force is always $G Mm/r^2$, but it is always directed towards the Sun, while the planet's velocity is not. Remember $\vec{F} = m\vec{a}$ is a vector equation. The gravitational force affects only the radial component, true, but in the next instant the radial vector itself has changed. For example, say the Sun is at the origin $(0,0)$ and the planet is momentarily at $(1,0)$ at $t=0$, but moves to $(2,1)$ at $t=1$. The radial vector points in the $-\vec{x}$ direction at $t=0$, but has changed at $t = 1$ (in particular we say it is $-2 \hat{i} - \hat{j}$). The direction of the force is now different, and furthermore, it was always changing while the planet was moving. Hence we need calculus, and the problem gets more complicated.

Answer (score -1):

I guess that you are using $$F = \frac{-GMm}{r^2} = m\frac{d^2r}{dt^2}$$ and wonder that all planets would be moving radially, with increasing velocities until hit the sun.

The point is that the $r$ in the denominator is simply the radial distance: $r^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$, but the $r$ in the derivative is a vector $r = (x,y,z)$. If written in cartesian coordinates, Newton's law of gravity translates in a system of 3 differential equations with 3 unknowns x,y,z. The solution is the orbit and depends on the initial conditions.

$$\frac{-GMmx}{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} = m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$$
$$\frac{-GMmy}{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} = m\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}$$
$$\frac{-GMmz}{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} = m\frac{d^2z}{dt^2}$$

Comment: Sorry for the edit but I downvoted instead of up.

Comment: Are you saying that $r=x+y+z$